# JavaCV - invert grayscale image, or convert binary back to grayscale

Tags: opencv, javacv

`HoughLinesP` fails with a binary image. So I cannot feed it directly the result of `cvThreshold`. It works fine with the input gray scale image. How can I directly invert the gray scale image without reducing to binary b+w, or how can I go back from b+w to gray?

Comment: `Image=1-Image` should invert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a mistake in the code, and actually `HoughLinesP` can be called with an `8U` input image.